# bootstrap 4 feedback text doesnt render properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, laravel, bootstrap-4

when literally copy pasting this from bootstrap 4:

```
<div class="form-group has-danger">
     <label class="form-control-label" for="inputDanger1">Input with danger</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-danger" id="inputDanger1">
     <div class="form-control-feedback">Sorry, that username's taken. Try another?</div>
     <small class="form-text text-muted">Example help text that remains unchanged.</small>
</div>
```

[I get this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DYhm.png)

Getting this with alpha 4 and alpha 5.

Maybe it's because I'm using flatkit and laravel/blade?

Comment: Are you using custom css?

Comment: can you share the html output via console?

Comment: It's not  b'coz of laravel. check your bootstrap css and js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently there was a file called app.css included in the public/css folder AND an app.css file included in the /assets/styles/ folder. By removing the first one it works like a charm. The second was probably a default css file made by laravel, it said bootstrap 3 in the comments so this one was definitely the culprit. Sorry for wasting your time folks :s

Answer (score 0):

Try with CSS:`https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="form-group has-danger">
  <label class="form-control-label" for="inputDanger1">Input with danger</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-danger" id="inputDanger1">
  <div class="form-control-feedback">Sorry, that username's taken. Try another?</div>
  <small class="form-text text-muted">Example help text that remains unchanged.</small>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In other css version, I could see this issue.